# File error for printing format issues

Tags: modifiers, stl

I am trying to set up a model on a Cura Lulzbot software to get a preview of what I am making but I am getting file errors even though I have it all unified with the boolean modifier. There are probably things I have missed so I have the file liked here
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jf9wnb6dgbw7gom/Print%20Error%20Model.blend?dl=0

Hopefully it's something simple I overlooked.

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of your question specific to the problem you are having and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Comment: Noted, I will make sure to do that better in the future.